# How to set image to vue-picture-input from vue function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In vue we can set the value of input field from vue function by using `v-model`. For example:

```
<form id="demo">
  <!-- text -->
  <p>
    <input type="text" v-model="msg">
    {{msg}}
  </p>
</form>

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    msg      : 'hi!'
  }
})
```

Then, we will have value `hi!` in the input field. But, how we can do the same thing in [vue-picture-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-picture-input)? It's not have v-model. I need to set image into `vue-picture-input` first to preview image before updating a model. I have tried to add `prefill` but after updating a model there is an error shown in the console: `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Comment: can you elaborate your problem

Comment: do you want to change the text on the input field or preload a image??

Comment: i want to preload an image

Answer (score 0):

`vue-picture-input` has a prop named prefill. You can use the prefill to load a preload image. Inpite of using `v-model` here you need to bind the `prefill` prop with the `imageURL`. Look at the demo below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-picture-input"></script>
  <title>In the browser!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <picture-input width="200" 
  height="200" :prefill="imgURL"></picture-input>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
        imgURL: "https://picsum.photos/200/200",
      },
      components: {
        'picture-input': PictureInput
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```